# What is causing this difference in performance in indexing between data.table and collapse

Tags: r, data.table

can someone explain to me where does this difference in performance come from.
From the bellow I understand that

- indexing is significantly faster in collapse than data.table
- taking first by index is also way faster

I probably do not understand what both packages are doing under the hood.
I checked GForce was enabled in data.table

code:

```
suppressMessages(library(collapse))                                        
suppressMessages(library(data.table))                                      
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)                                      
options(datatable.print.topn = 3L)                                         
                                                                           
# dataset                                                                  
set.seed(1L)                                                               
n_rics <- 500L; ric <- sprintf("A-%s",1:n_rics)                            
n_dates <- 1000L; date <- as.Date("2015-01-01") + 1:n_dates                
n_values <- 4L                                                             
DT <- CJ(ric, date, value = 1:n_values)[, value := runif(.N)][sample(1:.N)]
                                                                           
## indexing                                                                
                                                                           
DT1 <- copy(DT)                                                            
system.time({                                                              
    setindex(DT1, date, ric)                                               
})                                                                         
#    user  system elapsed                                                  
#   7.367   0.033   0.750                                                  
                                                                           
DT2 <- copy(DT)                                                            
system.time({                                                              
    DT2 <- fgroup_by(DT2, date, ric, sort = FALSE)                         
})                                                                         
#    user  system elapsed                                                  
#   0.165   0.004   0.169                                                  
                                                                           
## first by group                                                          
                                                                           
DT1 <- copy(DT)                                                            
setindex(DT1, date, ric)                                                   
system.time({                                                              
    f1 <- DT1[, .SD[1L], .(date, ric)]                                     
})                                                                         
#    user  system elapsed                                                  
#  16.118   0.072   1.523                                                  
                                                                           
DT2 <- copy(DT)                                                            
DT2 <- fgroup_by(DT2, date, ric, sort = FALSE)                             
system.time({                                                              
    f2 <- ffirst(DT2)                                                      
})                                                                         
#   user  system elapsed                                                   
#  0.017   0.000   0.017                                                   
                                                                           
identical(f1, f2)                                                          
# [1] TRUE
```

Using data.table_1.14.2, collapse_1.7.3

Comment: You might get better performance with `data.table` w/ `setDTthreads(0L)`. Btw. the indexing part is faster with data.table on my system.

Comment: Just tried and the result does not change much, anyway it's not really something I want to change each time I do a "unique by" operation, so I'll keep the default value

Comment: Timings are almost identical for me when `data.table` uses 4 threads (default on my machine)

Comment: @bretauv identical between data.table and collapse ? or 1 thread/4 threads ?

Comment: Identical between data.table and collapse when data.table uses 4 threads

Comment: Really ?? even the first by group ?

Comment: I will put my results in an answer so that you can see by yourself (note that I have more up to date versions of both packages)

Comment: Index does not carry enough informations for grouping. Code you are comparing is not apples to apples. Subscribe to this issue to be notified when it will change https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4387

Comment: ok @jangorecki feel free to add it as an answer. Although in that case you're saying collapse does more work ? Anyway looks like my problem is mostly the number of threads

Comment: at a glance, `unique(DT1, by = c("date", "ric"))` should do what you want? i suspect it'll be faster

Comment: I am saying that group by in DT is not utilizing index as well as it could.

Comment: @MichaelChirico it will be still slowish. In mergelist PR #4370 we have a fast version called fdistinct https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/2884b29519804c75081c4011daf7d7f7f1f96546/R/mergelist.R#L41

Comment: @MichaelChirico and timings https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2947#issuecomment-636472490 shows that speed up can be tremendous

Comment: @jangorecki will fdistinct be merged in 1.15/16 ?

Comment: @statquant why not 1.14.98? :-) I feel you are asking about 1-2 coming release. I wish it will (fdistinct is just a tiny piece of that PR actually), but it's not really up to me. Best if you will upvote/ask, in related issues/PRs.

Comment: @jangorecki I am not sure my opinion has any weight at all but I did message the issue. Very happy to reiterate on other linked issues but did not find any

Comment: @statquant your opinion there has Inf bigger weight there than here :)

Answer (score 2):

I have more or less the same time between `data.table` and `collapse` when `data.table` uses 4 threads. Your example below:

```r
suppressMessages(library(collapse))                                        
suppressMessages(library(data.table))                                      
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)                                      
options(datatable.print.topn = 3L)   

# what versions?
packageVersion("data.table")
#> [1] '1.14.5'
packageVersion("collapse")
#> [1] '1.8.9'

# how many threads?
getDTthreads()
#> [1] 4


# dataset                                                                  
set.seed(1L)                                                               
n_rics <- 500L; ric <- sprintf("A-%s",1:n_rics)                            
n_dates <- 1000L; date <- as.Date("2015-01-01") + 1:n_dates                
n_values <- 4L                                                             
DT <- CJ(ric, date, value = 1:n_values)[, value := runif(.N)][sample(1:.N)]

## indexing                                                                

DT1 <- copy(DT)                                                            
system.time({                                                              
  setindex(DT1, date, ric)                                               
})                                                                         
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.18    0.00    0.05

DT2 <- copy(DT)                                                            
system.time({                                                              
  DT2 <- fgroup_by(DT2, date, ric, sort = FALSE)                         
})                                                                         
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.05    0.03    0.07


## first by group                                                          

DT1 <- copy(DT)                                                            
setindex(DT1, date, ric)                                                   
system.time({                                                              
  f1 <- DT1[, .SD[1L], .(date, ric)]                                     
})                                                                         
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.20    0.03    0.10

DT2 <- copy(DT)                                                            
DT2 <- fgroup_by(DT2, date, ric, sort = FALSE)                             
system.time({                                                              
  f2 <- ffirst(DT2)                                                      
})                                                                         
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       0

identical(f1, f2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: yeah... I get a similar result, my box is using 27 threads by default.
sigh, it's a bit annoying though because I do not really want to tune this parameter.

Comment: Two points here, first, if you don't need na.rm = TRUE use ffirst(DT2, na.rm = FALSE), which will be many times faster than na.rm = TRUE because the grouping object (retrievable using GRP(DT2)) contains the starting positions in "group.starts", allowing ffirst to do a simple subset. Also nnote that the fastest way to do this overall operation is funique(DT, cols = .c(date, ric)).

Comment: Then, with sort = FALSE I use a very different algorithm from data.table based on hashing, which is indeed faster than radix ordering on moderately sized data in many circumstances. It is not parallelizable though, so you should expect data.table to become more competitive when you fire up the number of threads.

Comment: @Sebastian from my tests if I only want unique (date, ric) couples the fastest is to use fselect(., date, ric) %>% fgroup(., date, ric) %>% ffirst(., na.rm = TRUE, sort = FALSE)

Comment: The fastest solution in that case should be fselect(., date, ric) %>% funique()...

Comment: Ok, I had to use method = "radix" to make it faster, thanks @Sebastian

Comment: It depends. radix ordering is definitely fastest when data is already sorted, and also pretty competitive with numeric data stored as integer or doubles. With character vectors or factors, method = "hash" is very fast. Note that method = "radix" cannot provide first-appearance order of unique values, but will sort them if numeric.